# How to set relative scrollbar width?

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design

Just like the simple example [Here](https://codepen.io/uduru0522/pen/JjbqZMv),
I am trying to make the scrollbar width stay at like, 5% of the parent `<div>` width,
no matter how is the `<div>` resized.

However, when I change the original .css code

```css
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
    /* This works fine, just not what I want*/
    width: 30pt;
}
```

To this:

```css
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
    /* Nope? */
    width: 10%;
}
```

The whole scrollbar just disappears.

How should I do it? Or is it just unavailable?

Comment: It looks like relative widths aren't acceptable for scrollbars, which is why it disappears completely.  Also worth noting that `-webkit-scrollbar` only works for Webkit-based browsers - Firefox and IE will ignore any scrollbar styles set using it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I uses the `scrollbar-width` for them. Dunno if it works on IE though.

Comment: No, `scrollbar-width` it doesn't work in IE either

Comment: Well, its gonna be another problem and I think I could solve it. Back to this question, so I assume its not gonna be possible unless I rewrite the whole scrollbar thing is like, JavaScript?

Comment: You could do that in JS and manually calculate the width of the scrollbar.  Bit of a pain though - perhaps someone else will have an inkling as to how to get it working?